# I am trying to solve N queens using backtracking. My solution is calculating values, however, there is a problem with return logic

Tags: python, backtracking

Given n==4,
Return [[[".","Q",".","."],[".",".",".","Q"],["Q",".",".","."],[".",".","Q","."]],[[".",".","Q","."],["Q",".",".","."],[".",".",".","Q"],[".","Q",".","."]]]

Here is my code:

```
        def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
            ans=[]
            a=[['.' for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
           
            def valid(row, col):
                for i in range(n):
                    if a[i][col]=='Q':
                        return False
            
                for i in range(n):
                    if (row+i<n and col+i<n):
                        if a[row+i][col+i]=='Q':
                            return False
            
                for i in range(n):
                    if (row-i>=0 and col-i>=0):
                        if a[row-i][col-i]=='Q':
                            return False
            
                for i in range(n):
                    if (row-i>=0 and col+i<n):
                        if a[row-i][col+i]=='Q':
                            return False
                for i in range(n):
                    if (row+i<n and col-i>=0):
                        if a[row+i][col-i]=='Q':
                            return False
            
                return True
            
            def solver(rowNo):
                if rowNo == n:
                    
                  
                    ans.append(list(a))
                
                    return 
                
                for i in range(n):
                    if valid(rowNo, i):
                        a[rowNo][i]='Q'
                        solver(rowNo+1)
                        a[rowNo][i]='.'
                
                return 
            solver(0)
            return ans
```

When I check every possible time the base condition is encountered in solver function, it is solving the question correctly. However, the appended arrays in the ans variable are changing reference each time I change a. This results in ans array containing two a lists appended in their initial state of totally empty. I cannot understand why. Please help me understand.

Comment: It's obvious that this is a method inside a class. I recommend using `@staticmethod` because you are not using the argument `self`. This method has nothing to do with class instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in  the line `ans.append(list(a))`
you are copying one list,
but you should copy 8 of them

because `a` looks like this

```py
a = [
    ['.', '.', 'Q', ...],
    [...               ],
    ...
]
```

you have to copy each element of `a`
so

```py
ans.append([inner.copy() for inner in a])
# I also recommend to use `.copy()` instead `list(original)` to copy
```